# PowerShell: Batch Process - Running two Regex formulas one after another

Tags: regex, powershell

in the `File1.html` I have this html code

```
<ul id="sidebarNavigation">
<li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-1.html"; title="Page 1">Page 1 (34)</a></li>
<li> <a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-2.html"; title="Page 2">Page 2 (29)</a></li>
<li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-3.html"; title="Page-3">Page 3 (11)</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, I used 2 regex formulas, one after another, into PowerShell code, in order to get the result into `result.html`

This is the PowerShell Script with 2 simple regex:

**Regex 1:**
Find: `(?<=<li>)\s+` REPLACE BY: `CARPET`

**Regex 2:**
Find: `CARPET` REPLACE BY: `DOOR`

POWERSHELL CODE:

```
$path = 'c:\Folder1\file1.html'
$result = 'c:\Folder1\result.html'
Get-Content -Path $path | ForEach-Object{ 
       $one = ($_ -replace '(?<=<li>)\s+','CARPET')   | Out-File -FilePath $result -Append    
       ($two = $one -replace 'CARPET','DOOR')   | Out-File -FilePath $result -Append 
'Final = $two'
     }
```

The Output in `result.html` should be:

```
<ul id="sidebarNavigation">
<li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-1.html"; title="Page 1">Page 1 (34)</a></li>
<li>DOOR<a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-2.html"; title="Page 2">Page 2 (29)</a></li>
<li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-3.html"; title="Page-3">Page 3 (11)</a></li>
</ul>
```

The PowerShell code seems to be good, but the problem is that the second regex, on the `$two` doesn't make the replacement from `CARPET` to `DOOR`. I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

> ```
> $one = ($_ -replace '(?<=<li>)\s+','CARPET') | Out-File -FilePath $result -Append
> ```

You are trying to assign the output of the pipeline to a variable, but all output goes to the file, so the variable `$one` will be `$null`. The order of operations is this:

1. `($_ -replace '(?<=<li>)\s+','CARPET')` → outputs result of replacement to the pipeline
2. `| Out-File -FilePath $result -Append` → outputs nothing to the pipeline, so will be `$null` when captured in variable
3. `$one = $null`

---

> ```
> ($two = $one -replace 'CARPET','DOOR') | Out-File -FilePath $result -Append
> ```

Here you don't have this problem, because you assign to the variable first and then pipe the result of the assignment to `Out-File`. The order of operations is this:

1. `($two = $one -replace 'CARPET','DOOR')` → assigns result of replacement to variable and then outputs it to the pipeline
2. `| Out-File -FilePath $result -Append` → outputs nothing to the pipeline, but doesn't matter as the assignment has already been done

### Solution

It should be obvious now: To fix the first `-replace` statement simply set the parentheses like in the 2nd `-replace` statement:

> ```
> ($one = $_ -replace '(?<=<li>)\s+','CARPET') | Out-File -FilePath $result -Append
> ```

Another way is to use [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) to output to a file and a variable (or further pipeline commands) at the same time:

```
$one = ($_ -replace '(?<=<li>)\s+','CARPET') | Tee-Object -FilePath $result -Append
```

---

There is another error here:

> ```
> 'Final = $two'
> ```

It should be `"Final = $two"` as string interpolation only works within double quotes.

### Complete fixed code

```
$path = 'c:\Folder1\file1.html'
$result = 'c:\Folder1\result.html'
Get-Content -Path $path | ForEach-Object{ 
    $one = $_ -replace '(?<=<li>)\s+','CARPET'
    ($two = $one -replace 'CARPET','DOOR') | Out-File -FilePath $result -Append 
    "Final = $two"
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, sir. Can you put the entire code (updated by you) in order to test it and as to accepted as an answer? Because I change the code, but seems to be a little error . Check this  https://snipboard.io/6oav24.jpg

Comment: yes, almost good. But, as you can see in this print screen, your code duplicate the lines, instead of just replacing. Can you modify so that to do just the replace?  https://snipboard.io/6oav24.jpg

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu I see. You want to keep both `CARPET` and `DOOR` lines?

Comment: NO. I want to keep all the lines, the same lines, except the one that must have the ouput DOOR. Please read what I write at the beginning of this post. you will see the OUTPUT there ! But the replacement must be made after the first regex replacement.

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu I've removed the 1st `Out-File` in the the complete code. Is this what you want?

Comment: super answer, thanks. I marked as an answer.